# Issue with scaling viewport on mobile site

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, viewport, scaling

I have a mobile website and have disabled scaling however this fails when the user expands a left slide out menu.  How do I stop this from happening?

You can view the website at http://campmobile.bluelemonmedia.com/contactus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `.container { width: 420px; }` in the media queries, why not use `width:100%; max-width:420px;` because that would allow it to be at most 420px, but on screens smaller than this it will resize accordingly.